# PHP Script and Ubuntu Server Permissions Issue

Tags: php, apache2, ubuntu-11.04

First of I am new to PHP and Linux. I am having trouble trying to set up a file upload script.  It stops at the !is_writable. I feel like this is a permissions issue on the server but I have everything set to 777.  Am I missing something?

The server is a Ubuntu server set up as a virtual machine with local access.

**Code from page**

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
echo "<br/>";

//This gets all the other information from the form 
$name=$_POST['name']; 
$email=$_POST['email']; 
$phone=$_POST['phone']; 
$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);

//This is the directory where images will be saved 
$target = "testimages/"; 
$allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.bmp','.png'); // These will be the types of file that will pass the validation.
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 


$filename = $_FILES['photo']['name']; // Get the name of the file (including file extension).
$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1); // Get the extension from the filename.

// Check if the filetype is allowed, if not DIE and inform the user.
if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

// Check if we can upload to the specified path, if not DIE and inform the user.
if(!is_writable($target))
die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');

//Writes the photo to the server 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{ 

//Tells you if its all ok 
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
} 
else { 

//Gives and error if its not 
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
} 

// Connects to your Database 
mysql_connect("localhost","phptestuser","ct6697") or die(mysql_error()) ;
mysql_select_db("Testing") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

//Writes the information to the database 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO employees ( name, email, phone, pic) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$phone', '$pic')");
```

---

Tried both answers below and still isn’t working, any other suggestions?

**Listing from the ls  -al:**

```
drwxrwxrwx  9 root       root       4096 Nov  7 16:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root       root       4096 Nov  7 16:53 ..
drwx------  2 www-data   www-data   4096 Nov  7 15:05 .gnupg
-rwxrw-rw-  1 yoderman94 www-data   2464 Nov  8 07:31 Add.php
-rwxrw-rw-  1 yoderman94 www-data    629 Nov  7 15:27 ImageUpload.php
-rwxr--r--  1 yoderman94 yoderman94 2115 Nov  7 15:45 PHP_Test.php
drwxr-xr-x  2 yoderman94 yoderman94 4096 Nov  1 14:39 _mmServerScripts
-rw-r--r--  1 root       root        177 Oct 27 11:32 index.html
-rw-rw-r--  1 yoderman94 yoderman94   44 Nov  1 10:19 phpinfo.php
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data   www-data   4096 Nov  7 16:09 testimages
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data   www-data   4096 Nov  7 15:08 tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

try to `chown` - change owner of upload folder, to the web server, usually it is www-data;

just run something like : `sudo chown www-data:www-data ./testimages/`

and try to use absolute path to upload dir.

Answer (score 0):

```
$target = "testimages/";
if(!is_writable($target))
```

Suggestion: Try setting $target equal to the absolute path of the file , probably /var/www/testimages